# unconfigured column family in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I created a table with map in Cassandra. But when I try to access it is giving me unconfigured column family error. Do I miss some thing.  I am new to Cassandra.

```
cqlsh:testdb> show version
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.9 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]

cqlsh:testdb> describe table users_map;
<I>

    CREATE TABLE users_map (
      user_id text,
      first_name text,
      last_name text,
      todo map<timestamp, text>,
      PRIMARY KEY ((user_id))
    ) WITH
      bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
      caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
      comment='' AND
      dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
      gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
      index_interval=128 AND
      read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
      replicate_on_write='true' AND  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
      default_time_to_live=0 AND
      speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND`enter code here`
      memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
      compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
      compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};

</I>

    cqlsh:testdb> insert into users_map (user_id) values ('muthu');
           Bad Request: unconfigured columnfamily user_map
    cqlsh:testdb> select * from users_map;
           Bad Request: unconfigured columnfamily users_map
```

Thanks in advance. I am able to query all other tables in this key space.

Comment: I have the same condition.
Most of the my integration tests - including tests that run through the same queries - succeed; but one or two fail intermittently.

Answer (score 0):

You have got a typo in your CF name: `CREATE TABLE users_map` vs `insert into user_map`.

Comment: That was I typo when entering the Question. I corrected it in question. But the issue is  still there.